# Python Requests - Is it possible to get the "HTTP/1.1 302 Found" portion of the response?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm working through the python courses on edube.org.  One of the labs is to use the socket module, make a request, and print the first line of the response, which is the

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

line.  And they do provide sample output and show that line, so I know that is the correct output from the lab.  3 labs later, the task is to write the exact same program using the requests module instead of the socket module.  It emphasizes that the outputs of the new version should be identical.

> "Everything else should remain the same: the command line arguments
> and outputs have to be indistinguishable."

Is there any way to get this line, or is this a bug/misstatement in the lab?  According to the docs for the requests module, it *sounds* like response.raw should do it as "a file-like representation of the response", but it appears to just be a representation of the response content, not the entire response.

Answer (score 0):

`requests` does not have built-in method/property to get raw start line of HTTP response.

However to complete your task you can extract in manually from response object:

```py
def get_start_line(url: str) -> str:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)  # parameter needed to stop following redirects
    return f'HTTP/{r.raw.version / 10} {r.status_code} {r.reason}'
```

Which outputs text in desired format:

```bash
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```